# Integral conditions of measure preserving transformation

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be a transformation of probability space $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$. We know that $T$ is measure preserving iff

$$\forall f\in L^1(\mu):\int fd\mu=\int f\circ T\,d\mu.$$

Can $L^1$ in the above condition be replaced by $L^\infty$?

I searched for a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190400/a-condition-for-measure-preserving-transformation), which is weaker than this one and left no answer. "We know" is given directly from the book, so I also don't know the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\forall f\in L^{\infty}(\mu):\int fd\mu=\int f\circ T\,d\mu$. Then for any measurable set $E$ the equation holds with $f=\chi_E$ so $\mu (E)=\mu (T^{-1}(E))$. So $T$ is measure preserving.

Conversely, if $T$ is measure preserving then the equation golds for simple functions. Now use the fact that $f\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ implies $f$ is a limit in $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ of simple, functions.

For $L^{1}(\mu)$ the proof is same except that you approximate $f$ by simple functions in $L^{1}(\mu)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $T_\ast(\mu)=\mu$ iff the integral condition holds with $f$ an arbitrary characteristic function by definition. Then by taking linear combinations this is equivalent to the integral condition with $f$ a simple function. Finally by approximating an $L^\infty$ or $L^1$ function by an increasing sequence of simple functions this is equivalent to the integral condition with $f$ an $L^\infty$ or $L^1$ function.

The above works even when $\mu$ is not necessarily a finite measure. In the case of $\mu$ a finite measure one could alternatively use the fact that $L^\infty\subseteq L^1$, given the $L^1$ characterization.